# Excel formula referencing hidden table is returning zero when value should not be zero

Tags: excel-formula

I have worksheet that displays a table of data that was pulled in by Power Query from another workbook. This table is just a reference table and I have grouped the rows the table is in to make the worksheet less busy/easier to view for the users.

There is a lookup formula that pulls the necessary value from that reference table using table referencing.

```
=SUMIF(tableName[#Headers],TEXT(AB$7,"m/d/yyyy"),tableName[#Totals])
```

However, while the table is hidden/the grouping is collapsed, the lookup formula returns zero when it should return something not zero.

[image]

When the table is not hidden/the grouping is not collapsed, the lookup formula returns the correct value.

[image]

How do I force the lookup formula to return the correct value when the table is hidden/the grouping is collapsed?

Comment: This is very difficult to answer without a [MCVE].  Please [edit] the question to show the information, including some test data and the formula you are using so we can reproduce.

Comment: I'll see what I can do.